# SQL Select Columns WHERE value IN GROUP BY Clause BY Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

If one has a grouped result set. ie:

(result set)

```
Id (bigint), UserId (int), Field1 (varchar), Field2 (varchar)
=============================================================
1,           22,           'Job',            'Teacher'
2,           22,           'Car',            'Mustang'
3,           22,           'Age',            '35'
4,           47,           'Job',            'Clerk'
5,           47,           'Car',            'Corolla'
6,           47,           'Age',            '23'
7,           85,           'Job',            'Banker'
8,           85,           'Car',            'Volkswagon'
9,           85,           'Age',            '44'
```

How can one return a result set based on a unique column (in this case, UserId) and get Fields in a where clause based on specific case?

To Match This:

```
Id (bigint), UserId (int), Car (varchar), Job (varchar), Age (varchar)
======================================================================
1,           22,           'Mustang',     'Teacher',     '35'
2,           47,           'Corolla',     'Clerk',       '23'
3,           85,           'Volkswagon',  'Banker',      '44'
```

I know this is bad database design, but I am working with an old application.
I have tried union or joining based on a separate select query with no avail.

Any help is appreciate as I am not proficient in SQL.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using a key/value table instead of a normal table with columns for job, age and car? Key/value tables are a nuisance to work with in my opinion.

Comment: The `id` column in your result makes no sense. You should remove it.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Like I said, I know it's bad database design. It's a bigger application that depends on a specific result set structure (until we can revise the table and source code itself). I agree they are a pain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `userid` and use conditional aggregation to get the values.

```
select
  userid,
  max(case when field1 = 'Car' then field2 end) as car,
  max(case when field1 = 'Job' then field2 end) as job,
  max(case when field1 = 'Age' then field2 end) as age
from mytable
group by userid
order by userid;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try and use conditional aggregation and the `row_number()` window function.

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY x.userid) id,
       *
       FROM (SELECT t.userid,
                    max(CASE t.field1
                          WHEN 'Car' THEN
                            t.field2
                        END) car,
                    max(CASE t.field1
                          WHEN 'Job' THEN
                            t.field2
                        END) job,
                   max(CASE t.field1
                         WHEN 'Age' THEN
                           t.field2
                       END) age
                   FROM elbat t
                   GROUP BY t.userid) x;
```

(And by the way, it's "Volkswagen", not "Volkswagon".)

Answer (score 0):

You can join to the set an additional time for each extra field:

```
SELECT row_number() over (order by t1.UserId)
    t1.UserId, t1.Field2 As Car, t2.Field2 As Job, t3.Field2 As Age
FROM [MyTable] t1
LEFT JOIN [MyTable] t2 ON t2.UserId = t1.UserID AND t2.Field1 = 'Job'
LEFT JOIN [MyTable] t3 ON t3.UserId = t1.UserID AND t3.Field1 = 'Age'
WHERE t1.Field1 = 'Car'
ORDER BY t1.UserID
```

Probably the (currently deleted) conditional aggregation answer will work better, but it's nice to know your options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use self join

```
select t1.Id, t1.UserId, t1.Field1, t2.Field2, t3.Field3
from table_name t1
left join table_name t2 on t1.UserId=t2.UserId and t2.Field1='Car'
left join table_name t3 on t1.UserId=t3.UserId and t2.Field1='Age'
where t1.Field1='job'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL PIVOT

```
SELECT UserId, Job, Car, Age
FROM
   (SELECT UserId, Field1, Field2 FROM dbo.mytable) x
PIVOT (
   MAX(Field2) FOR Field1 IN (Job, Car, Age)
) AS pvt
```

PIVOT converts rows into columns by taking a value (`Field1`) as name for the new columns and aggregating another value (`Field2`) as the value for these new columns.

Comment: Interesting addition, this is easier to read. How does it look in terms of performance?

Comment: Never tested it, but probably better than self made solutions.